# iOS : Clone repository issue with pod install

Tags: ios, git, repository, clone, cocoapods

I am looking for some information regarding repository clone.
For example, I want to clone a repository, an workspace having Pods installed and so on.
What should I do next ? Is `pod install` enough or need something else ?
I am asking because I cloned a repository, having the latest commit, and I run `pod install` and get a lot of errors. For example : `Bolts/Bolts.h not found` and so on.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: which library u tried?

Comment: I use many in the project. `AFViewShaker` , `FacebookSDK`. And get plenty of errors, suggested as missing. Why does this happen ?

Comment: I think u need installing AFViewShaker for new project.is it right??

Comment: Even so .. i used `pod install` and still getting errors. Do not know the nature of those errors, showing as "not found" right after installing

Answer (score -1):

Use the following instructions to install **AFViewShaker** (via cocoapods)

1: Open terminal in your mac machine

2: **user-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ sudo gem install cocoapods**

**user-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ pod setup**
(you must install cocoa pods in your machine)//only one time installation is enough.

3: Move to your project location in terminal

```
e.g.:  user-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ cd Desktop
       user-MacBook-Pro:Desktop user$cd Sampleios7
       user-MacBook-Pro:sampleios7 user$ // we reached our project location
```

4: **user-MacBook-Pro:sampleios7 user$ touch Podfile** //create new podfile on your project path

5: **user-MacBook-Pro:sampleios7 user$ open -a Xcode Podfile**

Now You just created the pod file and opened it using Xcode! Ready to add some content to the empty pod file?
Copy and paste the following lines into the TextEdit window:

```
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
pod "AFViewShaker", "~> 0.0.2"
```

6:  user-MacBook-Pro:sampleios7 user$ pod install //wait sometime

7: From now on, be sure to always open the generated Xcode workspace **(.xcworkspace)** instead of the project file when building your project.Dont open (.xcodeProj)

Comment: I did, it works. Now I am looking to know what should I do when I clone from repository a project already existing, because I get errors if I try to run it right after I clone.

Comment: @razvanifteme after cloning the repo you need to run the pod install command for the project you cloned.